# How to apply function to vector list?

Tags: haskell, vector

I have a large nested vector that look like this:

```
import Data.Vector
let x = fromList [["a", "b", "12", "d"], ["e", "f", "34", "g"]...]
```

I would like to convert the strings to integers at position 2 in each nested list I was trying to do this with map and a comprehension like this:

```
let y = Data.Vector.map (\a -> read a :: Int) [i !! 2 | i <- x]
```

What am I doing wrong? I would like the output to be:

```
(("a", "b", 12, "d"), ("e", "f", 34, "g")...)
```

Comment: What would be the type of the result?

Comment: The type should be a nested tuple.

Comment: So what should happen if `length xs /= 4` for any `ys` in `x`? Perhaps you should start with a vector of 4-tuples.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a number of problems here.

First of all, the result of a list comprehension is a list, so you're calling `Data.Vector.map` on a list, which won't work. And the `x` inside the comprehension is a `Vector`, which is another type mismatch. Either use a list instead of a Vector (along with `Prelude.map`) or convert the list to a `Vector` (in which case you can't use a list comprehension).

Secondly, ignoring the list/`Vector` problem, `[i !! 2 | i <- x]` will give you a list containing only the elements at position 2 from each sub-list. Using your example, the comprehension would yield `["12", "34"]`. Then when you map `read` over it, you'll get `[12, 34]`, rather than the output you're shooting for.

Finally, the output you're wanting to see is not valid for lists or for `Vectors` in Haskell. Both types of container must be homogeneous, i.e. they cannot contain values of more than one type. A `[Int]` cannot contain `String`s, nor can a `[String]` contain `Int`s, but your desired output contains both. There are ways you can get around this using existential types, but chances are there's a better solution for your underlying problem than to try to build heterogeneous collections.

Edit: You edited the last part of your post to use tuples, so the above paragraph no longer applies. The first two problems I mentioned still exist, though.

If you start with a list of 4-tuples (`[(String, String, String, String)]`), you can get what you want like this:

```
> let x = [("a", "b", "12", "d"), ("e", "f", "34", "g")]
> map (\(a, b, c, d) -> (a, b, read c :: Int, d)) x
[("a", "b", 12, "d"), ("e", "f", 34, "g")]
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks much like you should use a more sophisticated data type than a 4-tuple, like

```
data YourType_StringNum = YourType_StringNum { ytsnLetters1 :: String
                                             , ytsnLetters2 :: String
                                             , ytsnNumber :: String
                                             , ytsnLetters3 :: String }
data YourType_IntNum = YourType_IntNum { ytinLetters1 :: String
                                       , ytinLetters2 :: String
                                       , ytinNumber :: Int
                                       , ytinLetters3 :: String }
```

(of course with better identifiers). Then define a function like

```
toYtin :: YourType_StringNum -> YourType_IntNum
toYtin(YourType_StringNum a b s c) = YourType_IntNum a b (read s) c
```

With that, your problem reduces to transforming a `Vector YourType_StringNum` to a `Vector YourType_IntNum`, and that's trivially done with `Data.Vector.map toYtin`.